# How to save the values of some range into a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I need to save the values of each cell of some range inside a variable in order to show these values later in a `label.caption`.

I wrote the next code :

```
Dim sngNum As Single
Dim rngNum As Range

If sngEvenavg > sngOddavg Then
    For Each rngNum In Range("A9:A13")
        sngNum = rngNum
    Next rngNum
ElseIf sngEvenavg < sngOddavg Then
    For Each rngNum In Range("A47:A51")
        sngNum = rngNum
    Next rngNum
End If`
```

I also tried:

```
If sngEvenavg > sngOddavg Then
    For Each rngNum In Range("A9:A13")
        sngNum = sngNum & vbNewLine & rngNum
    Next rngNum
ElseIf sngEvenavg < sngOddavg Then
    For Each rngNum In Range("A47:A51")
        sngNum = sngNum & vbNewLine & rngNum
    Next rngNum
End If
```

When I display `sngNum` in a `label.caption`, it only shows the value of the last cell in the range, however, I need **all** the values of each cell in the range.

Comment: Maybe you want an array of values?

Answer (score 1):

Try it like that

```
Dim vDat as variant

If sngEvenavg > sngOddavg Then
    vDat = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("A9:A13").Value2)
ElseIf sngEvenavg < sngOddavg Then
    vDat = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("A47:A51").Value2)
End If
' In case you have cell errors to avoid a type mismatch
Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(vDat) To UBound(vDat)
    vDat(i) = CStr(vDat(i))
Next i

vDat = Join(vDat, ";")
```

`vDat` will contain all values from the range separated by a semicolon.

Comment: Caveat: `Join` will fail with a type mismatch if any of the values are actually cell errors.

Comment: Is that a problem?

Comment: `CStr` will not accept a `Variant/Error` though, and you don't need to lose the variant subtype - I'd suggest `If IsError(vDat(i)) Then vDat(i) = vbEmpty`

Comment: Hm, I tested and Cstr did accepted a `Varian/Error` but maybe there are cases where my code still goes wrong. Your code is certainly more robust.

Comment: Huh, but `Error` can't be coerced into anything without throwing a type mismatch. `?CStr(CVErr(xlErrNA))` ...curious how you got it to accept a `Variant/Error`

Comment: I just tested  a `#DIV/0!` by `1/0`. And I just tested a `#NAME?` error, works as well.

Comment: Dang, you're absolutely right! But then, it stores `"Error 20xx"` into the array as a value.

Comment: Yes, right. If that is not needed/wanted the OP could use your suggestion.